# Disable(pc) keyboard swiping the Android viewpager on emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, swipe

In Android, I need a view pager fragment that can be moved only with buttons not by swiping. I created one by disable swiping with finger, but I have to lock it when user uses emulator on PC or connect (screen sharing) with the PC, and I got really stuck!
What tricks or work around are there?
Here is my custom view Pager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.enabled = true;
    }
    public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }


        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.enabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: "i need a view pager fragment that can be moved only with buttons not by swiping" -- the point behind `ViewPager` is for it to be used via swiping. Use something else, other than `ViewPager`, that is tied to your buttons (e.g., just run a `FragmentTransaction` to change contents).

Comment:  , this is verybad .. what if i change adapter count yo 1 each time i change page and enable it when button is pressed ? You think is a good idea ?

Comment: Not really. Just run a `FragmentTransaction` to change your contents. Or, if you are not using fragments for your pages, toggle visibility or run animations on views to change your contents.